# How add Interval on button tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, intervals

I'm trying to build an Application that camera takes image automatically in every one minute, I m trying to add interval on button tag means when an application run, after every one minute automatically capture the image

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class CameraFeed extends Component {

    processDevices(devices) {
        devices.forEach(device => {
            console.log(device.label);
            this.setDevice(device);
        });
    }


    async setDevice(device) {
        const { deviceId } = device;
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: false, video: { deviceId } });
        this.videoPlayer.srcObject = stream;
        this.videoPlayer.play();
    }


    async componentDidMount() {
        const cameras = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
        this.processDevices(cameras);
    }


    takePhoto = () => {
        const { sendFile } = this.props;
        const context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(this.videoPlayer, 0, 0, 680, 360);
        this.canvas.toBlob(sendFile);
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="c-camera-feed">
                <div className="c-camera-feed__viewer">
                    <video ref={ref => (this.videoPlayer = ref)} width="680" heigh="360" />
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.takePhoto}>Take photo!</button>
                <div className="c-camera-feed__stage">
                    <canvas width="680" height="360" ref={ref => (this.canvas = ref)} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to keep track of the interval ID

```
this.intervalId = null;
```

Then, you make your event handler that will be fired on the button's click, and that subscribes the `takePhoto` to an interval

```
takePhotoEachDelay = (delay = 60 * 1000) => {
  setInterval(this.takePhoto, delay);
}
```

When your unmounts, you need to unsubscribe from the interval to avoid any unwanted behavior.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  if (this.intervalId) { clearInterval(this.intervalId); }
}
```

finally,

```
<button onClick={this.takePhotoEachDelay }>Take photo!</button>
```